# CMS - Database Schema Review / Questions

Tags: mysql, database-design, schema

***Database Schema Review for CMS***

I'm in the midst of creating a Laravel application that will (hopefully) rival WordPress. The thought process is quite similar. Developers are able to create resources (custom post types), modify users, & roles and add custom fields with flexible content (similar to that of Advanced Custom Fields).

As this is one of my first big builds I have a couple of questions regarding fields & categories:

***Categories:***
A developer is able to add a resource (such as news, or posts) and each resource can have a category which is labelled and inputed into the category table. A category can belong to more than one resource. What I can't wrap my head around is how to separate these two tables (categories and category content), what might feature in a different table and what I might even name it!

***Fields*** An administrator is able to create field groups that can belong to resources or pages. A field group would contain an array a fields, which would contain data such as type (rich text, name, required, conditional logic etc..). How would this data look in a schema? Would would be best practice?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm new to this world! 
***Please feel free to provide any constructive criticism regarding this design.***

The ERD Diagram can be found here - [CMS - SqlDBM Link](https://app.sqldbm.com/MySQL/Share/Xu58uOAdSq8rUEvY2NHjzUGFrngIE8md_DYjF4jNYw0)

[image: Rev]

Comment: Any ideas? Thanks.